# Linq to SQL | Get all records where a foreign key doesn't exist

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-sql, left-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables:

```
Schools
-------
pk_school_id,
title
```

and

```
Business_Hours
--------------
pk_id,
fk_school_id
```

I want pk_school_id and title from School Table for all pk_school_id that does not exist as fk_school_id in Business_Hours table.

```
var Schools = (from b in Db.Language_School_Business_Hours
    join s in Db.Language_Schools on b.fk_school_id equals s.pk_school_id into lrs
    from lr in lrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
       LeftID = b.fk_school_id,
       RightId = ((b.fk_school_id == lr.pk_school_id) ? lr.pk_school_id : 0)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to achieve your goal, without join, just take elements that are not contained in Business_Hours table

```
   var Schools = Db.Language_Schools
   .Where(s => !Db.Language_School_Business_Hours
   .Select(b => b.fk_school_id).ToList().Contains(s.pk_school_id))
   .Select(x => new
    {
        x.pk_school_id,
        x.school_title
   });
```

Comment: This gave me an internal server error! I will just check what's wrong with this one!

Comment: let me know if you need help, write here the server error

Comment: This gives following error on debug.

base = {"The query operator 'AsQueryable' is not supported."}

Answer (score 1):

I think we can a bit simplify the linq by removing `.ToList()` after the first `.Select(...)`, removing the last `.Select(...)`. Pls take a look at a below code.

```
var schools = Db.Language_Schools
              .Where(w => !Db.Language_School_Business_Hours
              .Select(s => s.fk_school_id)
              .Contains(w.pk_school_id))
              .ToList();
```